# How to apply styles dynamically to a html table created in side a jquery function

Tags: html, jquery

I have dynamically created a table using JSON inside a function . I could not find a way to apply the  the qtip.js and its style to this dynamically created html table. Can anyone tell me a way to apply styles and qtip.js inside a jQuery function?

Comment: please add the code which you are trying..

Answer (score 0):

Could you add some sample code on jsfiddle.net ?
Did you consider about naming the html table in anyway and set the css rules anyways, so the come in place as soon as the table is rendered ? otherwise you could apply the styles after the table has been created by `$('table').css("width","200px");`

Comment: well the table has completely rendered using as a string .

Comment: could you please rephrase that sentence ? I don't get what your trying to say !

Comment: well it s like this . um creating a table var table_string = "<table class='common_data_grid top20' like this and um rendering it to a div

Comment: yeah than simply apply css styles to .common_data_grid top20{} ?

Answer (score 0):

Just obtain a reference to the element you dynamically created and apply qTip accordingly:

```
var table = $('<table></table>')
    .appendTo('body')
    .qtip({
        content: 'This is an empty table.',
        show: 'mouseover',
        hide: 'mouseout'
    })
```

Comment: The problem is i cannot figure out where to add the qTip.js in to this function

Comment: After you installed qTip (http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/docs/#installation), when you dynamically create the element using jQuery (like I did with the above), just call `qtip()` on the jQuery container and it will apply the tooltip to every element.

Comment: well this is how the qtip file i on js :<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/jquery.qtip.min.js"></script> how to call this from another .js file that i cannot figure put